Redefining the Meta-Turing Problem by Introducing an pinfHalt State
Abstract:
This proposal aims to approach the Turing Halting Problem by introducing the concepts of non-computable functions and an additional state, "pinfHalt," which denotes a program that halts only after infinite time. By redefining the problem through these concepts, I argue that the classical view of the Halting Problem might be reconsidered. I welcome critique and insights, particularly from those with a deep understanding of the Halting Problem.
Main Proposal:
To address the Halting Problem, consider the following thought experiment: Imagine one million programmers confined to a building tasked with analyzing a given program to determine whether it halts. Alternatively, if we consider our brains to be algorithmic, this task could also be assigned to AI agents. This setup prompts us to consider the predictability and nature of the problem.
Non-Computable Functions:
Non-computable functions are functions whose outputs cannot be determined through any algorithmic process. An example would be the task of predicting the n-th digit of a transcendental number without a closed-form formula. Without a complete understanding of the number in question, predicting its behavior or halting properties becomes impossible.
When these non-computable functions are executed within a theoretical supertask computer, we encounter scenarios where the function's result might only be produced after an infinite amount of time. In these cases, we introduce a new state termed "infHalt" to describe this outcome. An example could be an attempt to brute-force a solution to the Collatz Conjecture, where the solution may only be found after infinite computational steps.
Three-State Halting System:
This model leads to a machine that can produce three potential states for a given program:

Halts
Does Not Halt
Possibly Infinitely Halts (pinfHalt)

It is well-established in logic and computation theory that not every logical proposition is decidable. In this context, possibly infinite halts (pinfHalt) represent scenarios where the program's behavior remains indeterminate due to its reliance on non-computable functions.
Rethinking the Halting Problem:
The core issue with the Halting Problem lies in the paradoxical nature of its setup: We seek an answer in finite time for a problem that inherently involves infinite time. By reframing the problem in terms of non-computable functions, it becomes clear that this unpredictability resembles other random systems, such as those found in quantum mechanics, where entropy leads to unpredictability.
Conclusion:
This is a preliminary theory that I have been exploring. I recognize my lack of formal academic background in this area and am open to constructive criticism, particularly on potential contradictions within this approach. I invite experts in the Halting Problem to provide insights that could either refine or refute this proposal.

Relevent to the non-comp function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin's_constant#Algorithmic_randomness

The whole thing could be undestood as: we cant predict randomness with Turning machines.
which is self closing problem as the randomness is fundamantally zero information and we cant undersand something that we cant extract any information from it ... since we need to extract the informating from the system before we can understand it
